# Threading Parallel Invoke, Action

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, parallel-processing

My code as below

```
public void DownloadConcurrent(Action<string> Methord)
{
    Action<string>[] methordList = new Action<string>[Concurent_Downloads];

    for (int i = 0; i < Concurent_Downloads; i++)
    {
        methordList[i] = Methord;
    }

    Parallel.Invoke(methordList);
}
```

**Parallel.Invoke** is giving error:

```
"cannot convert from 'System.Action<string>[]' to 'System.Action[]'"
```

The Method it is calling is

```
public void DownloadLinks(string Term)
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check Parallel.ForEach like the following

```js
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> p = new List<string>() { "Test", "Test2", "Test3"};
        Parallel.ForEach(p, Test);
    }


    public static void Test(string test)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(test);
    }
```

This should do the trick for you

HTH
Dominik

Answer (score 2):

In your case it is easier if you use

> Parallel.ForEach

over your string list instead of using

> Parallel.Invoke

with additional parameter. Let me know if you want to stick to Parallel.Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.Invoke` accepts `Action` array while your code is passing it an `Action<string>` array. What you can do is :

```
public void DownloadConcurrent(Action<string> Methord)
{
    Action<string>[] methordList = new Action<string>[Concurent_Downloads];

    var r = methordList.Select(a => (Action)(() => a("some_str"))).ToArray();

    Parallel.Invoke(r);
}
```

You need to replace some_str with proper value for each action